# Right way to theme radios in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, radio-button, drupal-theming

I tried theming of radios in Drupal module overriding the following code in my theme function. For experimental I did not change anything in the below function and just migrated into my module with different name that would not conflict with original api function.

```
function theme_radios($element) {
  $class = 'form-radios';
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $class .= ' ' . $element['#attributes']['class'];
  }
  $element['#children'] = '<div class="' . $class . '">' . (!empty($element['#children']) ? $element['#children'] : '') . '</div>';
  if ($element['#title'] || $element['#description']) {
    unset($element['#id']);
    return theme('form_element', $element, $element['#children']);
  }
  else {
    return $element['#children'];
  }
}
```

Theme registration and all fine. Unfortunately, I am getting nothing as result. Only the form label (Radios's Label) I can see. Any idea please?

**EDIT:** I managed to solve it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: **EDIT:** I managed to solve it. Thanks everyone! I could see this question as unsolved in many places. I would try to write a blog post and publish the link in future if possible.

Comment: Remember you can always post an answer to your own question and select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is solved. I have posted a blog post on how to do it. Any one need help on similar issue can refer to the link.
http://www.encodez.com/blog/how-to-theme-radio-drupal-1.html

NB: This solution is for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 5):

**For Drupal 7** you'd have to dig a little deeper to fix this.

Start by creating `MY_THEME_form_element()`in your *template.php*, copy all the codes in `theme_form_element()` - you can get that from [api.drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7). Add a condition to check if the element is a radio button before the `switch($element['#element_display')` statement. Then create a new function to handle rendering the radio button differently.

```
if ($element['#type'] == 'radio') {
  $variables['rendered_element'] = ' ' . $prefix . $element['#children'] . $suffix . "\n";
  $output .= theme('form_element_label', $variables);
} else {
  switch ($element['#title_display']) {
```

From the above we are passing the rendering of the radio button unto the function `form_element_label()` so create `MY_THEME_form_element_label()` and the contents of `form_element_label()` into it. Edit this new function, replacing the return statement with this:

```
if (!empty($variables['rendered_element'])) {
    return ' <label' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $variables['rendered_element'] . $t('!title !required', array('!title' => $title, '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
} else {
    return ' <label' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $t('!title !required', array('!title' => $title, '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
}
```

This would give you a radio button placed within it's label rather than below or above it.

And finally, you can hook into **theme_radios** to add additional formatting to the way the list of radio buttons are rendered.

This answer was found at [this link.](https://www.silviogutierrez.com/blog/advanced-drupal-7-form-element-theming/) It describes a solution using a checkbox.

**NB** You can also apply this in formatting any element.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Try to add something more.

Comment: Wow, not it's better. +1